# how to display all the elements of a table?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to display all the information of my csv file. Except that in my visualforce page, he shows me the last element of my table.

```
public class ImportExcel {  

    public String fileName{get; set;}
    public Blob contentFile{get;set;}
    public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
    public String[] data{get;set;}

    public ImportExcel(){
        csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    } 
    public void readFile(){
        try
        {
            fileName=contentFile.toString();
            system.debug(fileName);         
            csvFileLines = fileName.split('\n');
            system.debug(csvFileLines); 
                for(integer i=0;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
                    data=csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                    system.debug('***'+data[0]+'**'+data[1]+'**'+data[2]+'**'+data[3]);
                } 

        }catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Please upload a valid CSV document');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
            return ; 
        }      
    }

}

<apex:page controller="ImportExcel">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
               <apex:inputFile value="{!contentFile}"  filename="{!fileName}"/>
               <apex:commandButton value="Import Excel" action="{!readFile}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
             <apex:pageBlock >
                {!data}
             </apex:pageBlock>      
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: My question is différent

Comment: please do not create duplicate accounts

Comment: Please substantiate your claim. In what way is it different? Including as much relevant detail as possible is something that will help garner positive attention and helpful, accurate answers. The reason why I've marked it as a possible duplicate is because there have been an influx of low-quality questions with very similar code in the past couple of days.

Comment: It's the same code, but it's two different questions IMO. The first was around a compiler error, this one is around a logic issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
for(integer i=0;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
    data=csvFileLines[i].split(',');
    system.debug('***'+data[0]+'**'+data[1]+'**'+data[2]+'**'+data[3]);
}
```

You're assigning an array of values from the current row (`csvFileLines[i]`) to `data`, on each pass through the loop, so it's always overwriting the previous row with the new one. If you need all the data elements individually you'll need a two dimensional array, but if you just want to display the info you could use the `csvFileLines` property directly.

`<apex:repeat>` is your friend when it comes to looping over a list in VF:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!csfFileLines}" var="line">
  <apex:outputText value="{!line}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

This should provide you enough to go on, I'll let you work it out from here. Side note: `fileName` is a pretty bad name for a property that is actually the file content ;)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer @Matt